# Sub panel voltage problem? 240v one leg?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

Just moved into a new house with peculiar wiring—-

Anyway i have a pushmatic sub panel in a shed about 75-100 feet away

It starts at the main panel (in garage)
With a 50amp breaker

One leg reads 120- one leg read 120
And ground = 0

By the time it reaches the sub panel
One leg reads 240v
And the other reads 120v
And the ground is 0

I’m assuming they maybe some looping back at the panel so I’ve disconnected
All other wiring and it’s still reading 240v one side—-

Before i pull out 75ft of wire (buried in conduit) to check for damage …
Is there anything else i should check?

Also i alway thought damage wire would make V less… not 240…

Thanks in advance

Comment: Confirm how you are taking the readings.  Should have 120 hot to neutral and hot to ground, 240 hot to hot, and 0 neutral to ground.  High volts on one leg is usually a lost neutral.

Comment: 120 hot to neutral on one side and

Comment: 240 hot to neutral on the other

Comment: Hot to hot reads 120

Comment: @NicholasBrennan -- are the readings at the shed taken from the busses/lugs of the subpanel, or...?

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting 120 hot-to-neutral and 240 hot-to-neutral on different busses, then the neutral is hot and one of the busses is actually neutral.  They are reversed.  Check against ground to confirm.

Comment: Man am i stupid - staring me in the face—- just didn’t occur to me cause my shed had power- lights and things worked…. But my unisaw was slow to start and super weak once i switched it to 220—- thought it wa the start capicitor….

Comment: Thank you so much- probly go to switch it over to square d box (already bought one- and a grounding rod) as soon as possible/